# Scala local variable inside primary constructor

Tags: scala, scala-primary-constructor

How in Scala I can define local variable in primary constructor?

I need to solve this exercise from `Scala for the impatient` book:

> Write a class Person with a primary constructor that accepts a string
>   containing a ﬁrst name, a space, and a last name, such as new
>   Person("Fred Smith"). Supply read-only properties firstName and
>   lastName. Should the primary constructor parameter be a var, a val, or
>   a plain parameter? Why?

And for now my solution looks like this:

```
class Person(firstLast: String) {
  private[this] val firstLastAsArr = firstLast.trim.split(" ")

  val firstName = firstLastAsArr (0)
  val lastName = firstLastAsArr (1)
}
```

How I can restrict `firstLastAsArr` variable visibility to primary constructor scope (now it have class scope)?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you define a local var/val in the primary constructor in Scala?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1118669/how-do-you-define-a-local-var-val-in-the-primary-constructor-in-scala)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One solution is to initialize `firstName` and `lastName` at once, thereby allowing to turn `firstLastAsArr` into a local temporary value inside your initialization block:

```
class Person(firstLast: String) {
  val (firstName, lastName) = {
    val firstLastAsArr = firstLast.trim.split(" ")
    (firstLastAsArr(0), firstLastAsArr(1))
  }
}
```

Comment: `firstLastAsArr(1)` will actually contain the separator, i.e., `" "`

Comment: @MalteSchwerhoff whoa? `"John Doe".trim.split(" ")` results to `Array(John, Doe)`

Comment: @om-nom-nom Interesting. I tried it locally as a Scala 2.10.1 script (https://gist.github.com/anonymous/5821751), but http://ideone.com/4b27Dr shows the behaviour as well with Scala 2.10.0.

Comment: @MalteSchwerhoff that is because you have **two** spaces in `"John  Doe"` and `(,1)` is the void between them

Comment: @om-nom-nom Oh boy, missing that is fairly embarrassing. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

It is not a general answer, but in this particular way you may write:

```
  val Array(firstName, lastName) = firstLast.trim.split(" ")
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't strictly need the intermediate variable:

```
class Person(firstLast: String) {
  val (firstName, lastName) =
    firstLast.trim.split(" ") match {case Array(first, last) => (first, last)}
}
```

However, if your transformation from `firstLast` to `firstName` and `lastName` grows a big longer, for example, because you check that there is exactly one first and one last name, then I would encapsulate the whole splitting-business in a dedicated method:

```
class Person(firstLast: String) {
  val (firstName, lastName) = split(firstLast)

  private def split(firstLast: String): (String, String) = {
    val firstLastAsArr = firstLast.trim.split(" ")
    ...
    (first, last)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Pattern matching in constructor works just fine, but you should consider moving such logic from constructor to factory method:

```
case class Person(firstName: String, lastName: String)
object Person{
  def apply(firstLast: String) = {
    val firstLastAsArr = firstLast.trim.split(" ")
    new Person(firstLastAsArr(0), firstLastAsArr(1))
  }
}

val p = Person("My Title")
```

Comment: @pagoda_5b: this is really not a correct answer in this case, but I can't add formated code sample to comment. I think the one who need to initialize 2 fields from 1 constructor parameter should use a factory method. SO is not about homework.

Comment: +1 for the factory method solution -- I'd also go for this pattern, as it avoids creating temporary tuples.

Answer (score 0):

Pattern maching in primary constructor works well

```
  class Person(_fullName:String) {
    val (firstName, lastName) =  _fullName.split(" ") match {
      case Array(x:String, y:String, _*) => (x,y)
      case _ => (null,null)
    }
  }
```

See my github for full answer
https://github.com/BasileDuPlessis/scala-for-the-impatient/blob/master/src/main/scala/com/basile/scala/ch05/Ex07.scala